# Simple example of confidence intervals

Tags: confidence-interval

I'm looking for an example for confidence intervals similar to the following but has only one continuous interval.  The following confidence interval is two separate set each of which only contain one value, which seem rather odd for being confidence interval:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: "*but does not involve a confidence interval that has only one continuous interval but not two separate intervals*" ... is confusing -- the first not combined with the second not suggests you *do* want two separate intervals. Can you clarify your language so we're not trying to guess how you intend such double negations ("not ...(not ... <something>)")?

Comment: Corrected wording.